# Why does a &[T] argument also accept &Vec<T>?

Tags: vector, types, rust

I am working through the Rust book, namely the [minigrep project](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch12-00-an-io-project.html). There I came across the following snippet:

```
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let (query, filename) = parse_config(&args);

    // --snip--
}

fn parse_config(args: &[String]) -> (&str, &str) {
    let query = &args[1];
    let filename = &args[2];

    (query, filename)
}
```

The confusing piece for me is `args: &[String]`. If I replace it with `args: &Vec<String>`, it also works. My guess is that `&[String]` is a more general type annotation that matches not only `&Vec<String>`, but also some other types. Is that correct? If so, what other types are matched by `[T]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking, [`[T]` is a contiguous sequence and `&[T]` is a slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html).

The reason why the compiler allows `&[String]` instead of `&Vec<String>` is that [`Vec<T>` dereferences to `[T]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#deref-methods). This is called [`Deref` coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion). It can be said that the former notation (in function parameters) is more general; it is also [the preferred one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-or). Further details about automatic dereferencing rules can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules).

Comment: `[T]` is not an array, because arrays are `[T; N]` with a statically known size. The [slice documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/) names `[T]` a *contiguous sequence*.. I'm not sure if this is the official term.

Comment: In contrast, the [Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html#array-and-slice-types) says `[T]` is a *slice* and `&[T]` is a *shared slice* often just called *slice*. This gets confusing :)

Comment: Yeah, it can be confusing; I guess `[T]`, `&[T]` and `&mut [T]` can all be referred to as slices, but the reference variants are most useful and thus that name stuck to them most.

Comment: NIT: [method call resolution](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) (referenced in the last link) works slightly differently than type coercion when passing a parameter since `self` can implicitly introduce an indirection `T -> &T`, something that isn't done for normal parameters.